# SVG rectangle blurred in all browsers

Tags: svg, browser

This SVG looks blurry in all browsers, at all zoom levels.

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="240" height="240" version="1.1">
  <rect width="200" height="200" x="20" y="20"
        ry="20" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#000" />
</svg>
```

In Chrome, Safari and Firefox it looks like this:

[image: blurry SVG]

If you zoom in you can see that the stroke has a two pixel width, even though the default stroke width is 1px. Manually setting it to 1px does not affect the output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has to do with the pixel rastering. The line-width is 1px and it is centered at (20,20). It is drawn between 19.5 and 20.5 px, so that the browser has to color both pixels to "use enough ink".

Solution: Use `19.5` as coordinates to be in the pixel raster.

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="240" height="240" version="1.1">
  <rect width="200" height="200" x="19.5" y="19.5"
        ry="20" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#000" />
</svg>
```

Edit:

In the following image, the blue dot has size of `1px` and is located (centered) at `(1,1)`. All four pixels will be colored to get a pixel image that is as close as possible to the not displayable dot.

[image: blue dot in pixel raster]

Comment: Do you have any reference for where it says that SVG will *center* its stroke width around the object outline (as opposed to drawing it inside or outside)?

Comment: @Gerrat, since not every path has an "inside" or "outside" (think of a straight line), I think this cannot be done in general (but no: I have not looked up this in the standard).